# Is there a way to define a ShellOption without value to check if it exists or not?

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I'm using Spring Shell for one of my projects, and I need a parameter to run my command with a different behavior like `--without-logs`.

Basically I need a `ShellOption` parameter to check if the parameter is given by the user or not.

Example:

`my-command --without-logs --other-opts`

`my-command --other-opts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, by default Spring Shell assign the option to true if we use that like only by option name.

Example:

`my-commnand --x` -> x is `true`

`my-command --x` false -> x is `false`